# R Language Error: "date_trans works with object of class Date only" (ggplot2)

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I used the melt() function from the "rehsape" library so that my data looks something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
    

Table_1 <- data.frame(

"Col_A" = c("2002-01", "2002-01", "2002-01", "2002-02", "2002-02", "2002-02", "2002-03", "2002-03", "2002-03"),
"Col_B" = c("AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "AAA", "ABB", "AAC", "AAA", "AAB", "AAC"),
"Col_C" = c(111, 122.5, 9, 727, 66.4, 3, 992, 88, 12)
    
)
```

Col_A is a date in the form : year-month

The columns from the table are in the following format:

```
Table_1$Col_A = as.character(Table_1$Col_A)
Table_1$Col_B = as.factor(Table_1$Col_B)
Table_1$Col_C = as.numeric(Table_1$Col_C)
```

From here, I use the melt() function:

```
melt = melt(Table_1, id = c("Col_A"))
```

Now, I want to plot this data in the following form:

```
p = ggplot(melt, aes(x = Col_A, y=value, group = 1)) + geom_line(aes(color=variable)) + facet_grid(variable ~., scales = "free_y")
```

My real data is a bit more complicated and I am trying to modify the dates (I have a lot of dates) so that they do not appear as cluttered.

I am trying:

```
 p = ggplot(melt, aes(x = Col_A, y=value, group = 1)) + geom_line(aes(color=variable)) + facet_grid(variable ~., scales = "free_y") + scale_x_date(date_labels = "m%-%y", date_breaks = '1 month') + theme(axis.text, x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

followed by:

```
final = p + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

But, I am getting this error: `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You don't have any date values. Is `2002-01` supposed to be a date? it needs month,day,year to be a date. R as a separate data type for dates so you would need to convert to that from character. Are those year/months? Do you want to assume that each value is from the first of the month?

Comment: I think your dates are stored as characters instead of the dedicated date/datetime classes, so it might be worth converting these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that while using `melt` you have combined numeric and character values together which has made `value` column as character so the numbers that you see are actually characters and not numbers.

To solve the issue at hand you need to convert `Col_A` column to date class to use `scale_x_date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

melt %>%
  mutate(Col_A = as.Date(paste0(Col_A, '-01'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Col_A, y=value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=variable)) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~., scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%y", date_breaks = '1 month') + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 45))
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to work! Can you please explain the logic behind this line of code:   mutate(Col_A = as.Date(paste0(Col_A, '-01'))) %>% ... why "paste"? why ""-01"? thanks!

Comment: @Noob `paste0` simply joins strings together, so `paste0("stack", "overflow")` produces the string `"stackoverflow"`. In order for character strings to be interpreted as a date, they need to be in the format "YYYY-mm-dd" but yours are in the format "YYYY-mm", so they need a "-01" stuck on the end of them to turn them into the correct format for reading as dates.

Comment: thank you for your reply! if my dates are in character format (whether y-m-d, m-d, y-m, etc), can I always use "paste0" to solve this problem?

Comment: not always. You need to change the code based on the format of your date. Here you had date in standard format (Y-m-d) so using `as.Date` without any format specification was enough. But if you have dates in another format you may pass specific format to `as.Date`. Moreover, there are functions like `ymd`, `dmy`, `mdy` etc in `lubridate` which can help you convert to dates easily.

Comment: On my own data, i  keep getting this error when running your code. Error : at least one layer must contain all faceting variables: 'variable'. Plot is missing 'variable'. Layer 1 is missing 'variable'. Do you know what could be causing this problem? Is it possible to just add one line of code that changes the date type ...and then i can go back to using ggplot the way i was before? Thanks

Comment: This is the line needed: Table_1$Col_A<-as.Date(paste0(Table_1$Col_A,"-01"))